# How can I work around the fact that in C++, sin(M_PI) is not 0?

Tags: c++, trigonometry, cmath

In C++,

```
const double Pi = 3.14159265;
cout << sin(Pi);                          // displays: 3.58979e-009
```

it SHOULD display the number zero

I understand this is because Pi is being approximated, but is there any way I can have a value of Pi hardcoded into my program that will return 0 for sin(Pi)?  (a different constant maybe?)

In case you're wondering what I'm trying to do:  I'm converting polar to rectangular, and while there are some printf() tricks I can do to print it as "0.00", it still doesn't consistently return decent values (in some cases I get "-0.00")

The lines that require sin and cosine are:

```
x = r*sin(theta);
y = r*cos(theta);
```

BTW: My Rectangular -> Polar is working fine... it's just the Polar -> Rectangular

Thanks!

**edit:**  I'm looking for a workaround so that I can print sin(some multiple of Pi) as a nice round number to the console (ideally without a thousand if-statements)

Comment: 3.58979e-009 is very close to zero. That is because the Pi you are using is also an "approximate" value of Pi.

Comment: yeah i know WHY it's doing that (I mentioned that in the post)... I'm looking for a workaround

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Have you tried just making your `Pi` more accurate (eg. by using the predefined constant `M_PI`)?

Comment: Round the sin output to some precision that guarantees sin(PI) will be zero.

Comment: 0 == 3.58979e-009, for very large values of 0...

Comment: For the record, the exact value is able to be calculated using atan(1) * 4.  Whether it reflects the value that is known today is a matter of how up-to-date your C library is as well as its limitations.

Comment: @Dustin: That's still not the *exact* value, see "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know..." above.

Comment: @Dustin:  cout << sin(atan(1) * 4) still doesn't print zero though...

Comment: Title is funny: "the fact that in C++, sin(3.14159265) is not 0" - it's not just in C++ but everywhere.

Comment: I think you missed my point - it's not C++ related, but IEEE754 or finite floating point in general.

Comment: No you clearly said the title was wrong because sin(Pi to eight digits) isn't zero in math (not just c++).  You are obviously right (Pi doesn't terminate) but it's irrelevant to the question.  It doesn't look good printing out 0.0000001 (or w/e) as the result of sin(Pi), so the question was how to deal with the fact that M_Pi (which in my case was 3.14159265) is approximated.  Everyone seems to have understood that fact except for the one person (you) who decided to be pedantic about the title.

Comment: Rotate/shift everything so that the value you care about works out to an exact result.  `cos(0)` exactly equals 1, `sin(0)` exactly equals 0, `cos(pi)` exactly equals -1, `sin(pi/2)` exactly equals 1, etc.  I'd try to use one of the zeros, though, because those are guaranteed to work everywhere.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (edit: also got linked in a comment) is pretty hardcore reading (I can't claim to have read all of it), but the crux of it is this: you'll never get perfectly accurate floating point calculations.  From the article:

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits requires an approximate representation.

Don't let your program depend on exact results from floating point calculations - always allow a tolerance range.  FYI 3.58979e-009 is about 0.0000000036.  That's well within any reasonable tolerance range you choose!

Comment: yeah I tried having a threshold such that anything within some really small range of a integer gets rounded to that integer, but I must have picked too big of a range because I kept falsely rounding other numbers that I didn't intend to.

Comment: `if (fabs(x - y) < 0.000001)` should do the trick.  It will be true if x is very nearly equal to y (in this case y is 0).

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for... I made an attempt at this on my own but my threshold constant was too loose.  This seems to work well enough.

Comment: actually now that I think about it, my threshold was stricter than that... I do, however, think I may have left out the absolute value function.

Answer (score 15):

Let's put it this way, `3.58979e-009` is **as close** to 0 as your `3.14159265` value is to the real Pi.  What you got is, technically, what you asked for. :)

Now, if you only put 9 significant figures (8 decimal places) in, then instruct the output to also display no more, i.e. use:

```
cout.precision(8);
cout << sin(Pi);
```

Comment: Eh?  It's almost exactly the same distance away (as you would expect from Taylor's theorem).

Comment: @Mike, it was just a parable... in the non-mathematical sense. :)  OK, in the interest of science it is now correct.

Comment: that's actually what I have right now, but I keep getting -0.00 for certain inputs and the only way I can think of to bypass -0.00 involves using sprintf() and comparing it to "-0.00" and hardcoding in the correct value.

Comment: @Vlad: Darn, now I better find some other nits to pick! :)

Comment: Just tried to build your example in VS2010 and it didn't worked. Still getting the non-approximated result...

Comment: (other than the -0.0000000 thing)

Comment: actually adding 0.0 fixed my negative zero problem (although the post that suggested me do that mysteriously disappeared)

Answer (score 4):

it's equal to zero if your equality operator has enough tolerance

Answer (score 4):

Did you try M_PI, available in most `<cmath>` or `<math.h>` implementations?

Even so, using floating point in this way will always introduce a certain amount of error.

Comment: yeah unfortunately cout << sin(M_PI) is still not zero

Comment: well you know what they say:  close only counts in horseshoes and decimal approxima... wait a second!

Answer (score 4):

This should display zero:

```
cout << fixed << sin(Pi);
```

(I don't think you should be trying to round anything. If you are worried about display, deal with the display functions, not with the value itself.)

Comment: +1: this is one of the few answers on the page that actually produces the desired output.  Only problem is you have to add 0.0 to sin(Pi) in order to avoid getting -0.0 as a result in certain cases.  For that reason I prefer the answer that I selected to be the "accepted answer."

Answer (score 3):

3.58979e-009 this is 0,0000000358979

Is a ~~0 like yours ~~PI.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw in some more digits to get a better result (try for example 3.1415926535897932384626433832795029L), but you'll still get rounding errors.

Still, you can create your own `sin` and `cos` versions that check against your known Pi value and return exactly zero in those cases.

```
namespace TrigExt
{
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

    inline double sin(double theta)
    {
        return theta==PI?(0.0):(std::sin(theta));
    }
}
```

You may also expand this thing for the other trigonometric functions and to handle Pi multiples.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little wrapper function:

```
double mysin(const double d) {
    double ret = sin(d);
    if(fabs(ret) < 0.0000001) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        return ret;
    }
}
```

As others have noted, floating-point maths is notoriously inexact. You need some kind of tolerance if you want something to appear as exactly zero.

Comment: You might also need a comparison for near 1.0 as well.

Comment: What about values that should equal exactly 0.5 etc?

Comment: You're never going to get exactly ½√3, so in the end you'll have to admit the limitations of binary floating point.

Answer (score 1):

why not force to however many digits you need

```
 int isin = (int)(sin(val) * 1000);
 cout << (isin/1000.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

sin(PI) should equal 0, for an exact value of PI. You are not entering the exact value of PI. As other people are pointing out, the result you are getting rounded to 7 decimal places is 0, which is pretty good for your approximation.

If you need different behavior you should write your own sine function.

Comment: For an exact value of PI and an exact implementation of sin.  Binary computers accommodate neither.

Answer (score 0):

If you use float or double in math operations you will never have exact results.
The reason is that in a computer everything is stored as a power of 2. This does not translate exactly to our decimal number system. (An example is that there is n o representation in base 2 of 0.1)

In addition float and double are 64 bits at least on some compilers and platforms. (I think - somebody correct me on that if needed). This will cause some rounding errors for either very large values or for very small values (0.0000000000xxx)

In order to get exact results you are going to need some big integer library.

As written in the comments to the question above see the site ...
http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

```
double cut(double value, double cutoff=1e-7) {
  return (abs(value) > cutoff)*value;
}
```

this will zero values below threshold, use it like this `cut(sin(Pi))`

Comment: a note to the wary: abs(double) does what is intended in C++, but not in C.

Answer (score -1):

More significant figures might help.  My C compiler (gcc) uses the constant `3.14159265358979323846` for M_PI in "math.h".  Other than that, there aren't many options.  Creating your own function to validate the answer (as described in another answer to your question) is probably the best idea.

Comment: Why is the Python one different after the 15th decimal place?

Comment: *shrug*  I'm just providing information that I have.  It appears that the Python one is inaccurate...  It is now removed.  :P

Comment: Looks like you are using a double for that.  Additional digits won't help at all.

The correct figures are
3.141592653589793  2384626433...

Comment: The Python one is wrong. Or rather, it's being displayed in more digits than its accuracy warrants.

Comment: The closest `double` approximation of pi is 3.141592653589793 115997963468544185161590576171875.  This is accurate to 16 significant digits, but Python prior to 3.1 always had `repr` return 17 significant digits.

Answer (score -1):

You know, just for the mathematical correctness out there: sin(3.14159265) **ins't** zero. It's *approximately* zero, which is exactly what the program is telling you. For calculations, this number ought to give you a good result. For displaying, it sucks, so whenever you print a float, make sure to format the number.

I don't really think that there are any float mechanics in the work here... it's just simple math.

About the code though, be careful... doesn't make your code give the wrong result by making the approximations before the display, just display the information the right way.