# Why in Common Lisp, when I run the function "acos" with an argument of 1, is the answer is wrong?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

instead of the correct answer of 0 when I run (acos 1) in, to find the ArcCosine of 1 emacs, I get the answer

`-6.125742f-17`

why is that and how do I get the correct answer of 0 like Windows Calculator says it should be

I'm using SBCL as my Lisp Interpreter on Windows 8 and SBCL is 32-BIT

when I run:

`(acos (rational 1))`

i get the same answer and when I run

`(acos (float 1))`

i get this error

```
The value -6.1257422745431e-17
is not of type
  (DOUBLE-FLOAT 0.0 3.141592653589793).
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

Comment: If you have specific SBCL questions, then you best ask on the SBCL support mailing list.

Comment: @RainerJoswig It's not SBCL-specific.  Floating point accuracy affects all languages. Similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670999/how-can-i-work-around-the-fact-that-in-c-sinm-pi-is-not-0

Comment: @finnw: there is a specific SBCL error condition mentioned, worth of a bug report. Plus: other CL implementations, for example SBCL on my Mac, compute (acos (float 1)) to 0.0.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer to [sin(M_PI) is not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670999/how-can-i-work-around-the-fact-that-in-c-sinm-pi-is-not-0) is applicable here as well:

You need to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and realise that all floating point computations are approximate and the approximation you got is "good enough".

As for the `SBCL` error, you should [report it to the SBCL maintainers](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html).

Comment: user2368426: If the answer helped you you should accept it. You have asked 13 questions, received answers for many of them and not accepted one. Give credit where it is due